# Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: wordpress

When I'm loading my wordpress website it is showing this error message "Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ZERO_RESULTS". How can I fix it?

Comment: I did not see any error message. Website loads fine.

Comment: Are you using free or purchased theme ??

Comment: @Priyanka Modi  It is purchased theme.

Comment: @Octavia - which is the theme name you use it in your project??

Comment: Your website uses "Google Maps JavaScript API" which requires authentication via api-key. The google maps api must be called either by your theme or one of the plugin. You will need to register for the google maps api, generate the api-key and use it on your website.

Comment: @Priyanka Modi I used this theme https://themeforest.net/item/incharity-wordpress-theme-for-charity-fundraising-nonprofit-organization/14802070

Comment: @Octavia Please follow my comment If I have answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you may forget to activate the Geocoding API in Google Cloud Platform.

So, You can try to create an account with Google Cloud Platform. The system produced a code and you can paste it in

**Theme Setup > Content Setup > Geolocation & Google Maps > API Key**

**Then clicked on Save.**

Once activated, it started to work just fine.

I hope that it works !!